# Filter child of sqlalchemy relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building an app that shows a database of different plant species. Each user sees the same table of plant species except for the "notes" column, which each user can edit to their own liking. This is the database structure I have created:

```
from datetime import datetime
import sqlalchemy as sa 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine) 
session = Session() 
Base = declarative_base()

class Note(Base): 
    __tablename__ = "note"
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    content = sa.Column(sa.Text(), nullable=False) 
    plant_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("plant.id")) 
    user_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey("profile.id"))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.id} -> {self.content}, user: {self.user_id}>"

class Plant(Base): 
    __tablename__ = "plant" 
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    common_name = sa.Column(sa.String(200), nullable=False) 
    date_created = sa.Column(sa.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow) 
    notes = relationship("Note", backref="user_notes")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.common_name}; n: {self.notes}>"

class Profile(Base): 
    __tablename__ = "profile" 
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True) 
    username = sa.Column(sa.String(200), unique=True, nullable=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

profile1 = Profile(username="profile1") 
profile2 = Profile(username="profile2") 
session.add(profile1) 
session.add(profile2) 
session.commit()

plant1 = Plant( common_name="plant1", notes=[ Note( content="plant1 note1", user_id=profile1.id ),  Note( content="plant1 note2", user_id=profile2.id )  ] ) 
plant2 = Plant( common_name="plant2", notes=[ Note( content="plant2 note2", user_id=profile2.id ) ] ) 
session.add(plant1) 
session.add(plant2) 
session.commit()
```

I have tried to get all the plants for user 2, which means writing a query to filter out all the notes of the other users (in the example user 1).

I have tried:

```
session.query(Plant).filter(Plant.notes.any(user_id=profile2.id)).all()
```

Unfortunately, this also gives me the notes of user 1, how to I write the correct query for this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with:

```
    plants = Plant.query.order_by(Plant.date_created).all()
    for i , plant in enumerate(plants):
        user_notes = [n for n in plant.notes if n.user_id == USER_ID]
        plants[i].notes = user_notes
```

Is there also a sql way to filter this?